# Ionic life-cycle not firing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an `Ionic 2` app which was working perfectly fine. I updated the ionic app from `rc-0` to `rc-2`. From then onwards I am facing an issue with ionic life-cycle event `ionViewDidLoad`. I have a signup form.

```
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup , AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';
export class Signup {
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(  formBuilder: FormBuilder) {  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      email: ['', CustomValidator.emailValidator],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(8),Validators.required])],
      password_confirmation: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(8),Validators.required])]
  } }
}
```

And in my html page I have,

```
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="signup()">
```

But when the page loads , I get an exception in my web-console

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./Signup class Signup - inline template:9:8 caused by: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.
```

I believe the `form` variable is not defined before the html is loaded. I tried `ngOnInit` and it works fine. `ionViewDidLoad` was working before I updated `Ionic` and most examples online mentions the above method only. What happened now, what changed ?

Comment: Try initializing your form in your constructor. That is the place I'm initializing it.

Comment: I could get it working using ngOnInit . But was not sure why ionViewDidLoad didnt work . Its better to avoid adding things to constructor , even though it wouldnt matter much here.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion? Problem to seems like your view gets rendered before your form is created.

Comment: I didnt try your solution, but I am sure it would work. As I mentioned ``ngOnInit`` worked, so the problem is with ``ionViewDidLoad`` running after the ``html``are loaded. Shouldnt it be called before that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has been a breaking change in `RC2` . As per new change ,

> ionViewDidLoad, means that everything has been already loaded!
>   including children. So if you template uses items and it undefined.

We can use the new `ionViewWillLoad`

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group();
}
```

Comment: where? Those docs are not yet updated. Got it from this issue . https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/8449

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you exactly what's going wrong. While compiling/rendering your view, Angular requires a formGroup instance to already exists. While ionViewDidLoad get's called after compiling/rendering your view, the ionViewDidLoad would not be called, because an error appeared within your template. To make things clear :

Define your form in constructor or ngOnInit, else your template wouldn't have access to the formGroup instance, since it haven't been created yet.